# How to send greek characters with HTTP post?

Tags: java, objective-c, json, http, utf-8

I create a request in objective c with this code:

```
NSString *urlBasic = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8080/belka/Login?"];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[defaults objectForKey:@"userID"], @"userID", @"login", @"login", [defaults objectForKey:@"userName"], @"userName", [defaults objectForKey:@"userFirstName"], @"userFirstName", [defaults objectForKey:@"userLastName"], @"userLastName", nil];
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict
                                                       options:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                         error:&error];
NSString *s=[urlBasic stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:s];
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSError *error;
        NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        if ((data.length > 0) && (error == nil)) {
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:NO];
        }
    });
```

In the defaults, userFirstName and userLastName are in greek. When i print "jsonData" description the greek characters are ok. When i print http body i get:

> `<7b227573 65724669 7273744e 616d6522 3a22ce9c ceb1cebd cf8ccebb ceb7cf82 222c226c 6f67696e    223a226c 6f67696e 222c2275 7365724c 6173744e 616d6522 3a224b61 72616d61 6e697322 2c227573 65724944 223a2231 30313532 38313637 33333732 33313638 222c2275 7365724e 616d6522 3a224d61 6e6f6c69 73204b61 72616d61 6e697322 7d>`

After the request is sent, on the side of server, which is in java, i have :

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
    String line = null;
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
          jb.append(line);
      } catch (Exception e) { /*report an error*/ }

    try
    {
        InitialContext ctx2 = new InitialContext();
        UserTransaction utx = (UserTransaction) ctx2.lookup("java:module/UserTransaction");
        utx.begin();
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject(jb.toString());
        String facebookID = data.getString("userID");
        String name = data.getString("userFirstName");
        String surname = data.getString("userLastName");
        String username = data.getString("userName");
        System.out.println(name);
        //and other . . . 
        utx.commit();
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getOutputStream().write(name.getBytes());
    }   
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem is that when i try to print name i get this : ÎÎ±Î½ÏÎ»Î·Ï
And this name is sent back to the ios device as response, which is like this:
     response = "\U00ce\U009c\U00ce\U00b1\U00ce\U00bd\U00cf\U008c\U00ce\U00bb\U00ce\U00b7\U00cf\U0082";
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error must be in the last bit of the chain, the piece of code not shown here that prints the response and that makes you think the transmission is broken.

The iOS client and the Java server can understand each other, and in fact the response is Μανόλης (I can't speak Greek, but it seems the text you were looking for)

The text you see `ÎÎ±Î½ÏÎ»Î·Ï` is the same sequence of byte interpreted as some 7-bit encoding (maybe CP1252, aka Latin 1 or CP1253, the Greek code page, I can't tell because there seems to be a problem with the StackOverflow font, or anyway my test program could not produce that output)

<sub>[Here is the program](https://gist.github.com/RaffaeleSgarro/1e228f3a25e77016567e#file-output-txt-L79) I used to analyze the "incorrect" response you posted at the end of your question</sub>

Comment: The response you mentioned (Μανόλης) is what i want. If the bytes are correct in every part of this question, how can i print the greek characters when i want?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", request.HTTPBody.description); (for the first print of the question). On the side of the server System.out.println(name); and i get ÎÎ±Î½ÏÎ»Î·Ï. And the respone in iOS NSLog(@"%@", response.description); and i get response = "\U00ce\U009c\U00ce\U00b1\U00ce\U00bd\U00cf\U008c\U00ce\U00bb\U00ce\U00b7\U00cf\U0082";

Comment: I hope that `\UXXXX` is the escape sequence for unicode characters in Objective-C, but still can't understand why you see it. Anyway, the sequence of byte is correct, so the error is in the server code, either the octets → String conversion (maybe made by the container) or just the String → output transmission. Put a breakpoint in the server code at the priting line, and tell if the String is Μανόλης or ÎÎ±Î½ÏÎ»Î·Ï

Comment: In the program you used to see Μανόλης as UTF-8 encoding, the str you used has \\ while my response is with one \. Is there something i should do about this? I am sorry for asking you all the time but i am trying to solve this two days.

Comment: Put the breakpoint in the server code and post what you see. My program has been written to answer your question, so must convert text to bytes and the backslash must be escaped in a Java string

Comment: What i see from debug is  ÎÎ±Î½ÏÎ»Î·Ï